# How to remove the citation from list of figures and start from the first chapter?

Tags: citing

I am writing my thesis and using natbib package with \citep for citation. I need to to start the citation numbering from the first chapter (\chapter{Introduction} [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4c5A.png)), but the first citation appears in the list of figures and the citation I do in the first chapters starts from [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aConr.png) as you can see from the code below. If you could please help to start the citation from the first chapter.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{utmthesis}
%According to the new manual, should not mixed single-side with two-side printing
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\chapter{Introduction}


\section{Background of the Study}
\citep{doi:10.1086/498806}  and \citep{Abe:1995hr, D0:1995jca}.


\begin{figure}[h]
   \begin{centering}
       \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./figs/tt3}
       \par\end{centering}
   \caption{This figure is adopted from \citep{Twiki4}.}
   \label{fig5}
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{utmthesis-numbering}
\bibliography{ref.bib}

\end{document}
```

[image: List of Figures]

[image: Chapter 1]

Comment: You can use the optional argument of `\caption` to give a caption without cite for the LoF: `\caption[Caption without citation]{This figure is adopted from \citep{Twiki4}.}`. Alternatively, https://ctan.org/pkg/notoccite might help. That won't disable citations in LoF and friends, but it will avoid the numbering getting confused by the LoF.

Comment: Off-topic, for most intents and purposes you don't need `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` (especially if you write in English). `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (without the `x`) is enough. In modern versions of LaTeX, `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is the default, so the `inputenc` call may be removed completely.

Comment: Thanks a lot. "Alternatively, ctan.org/pkg/notoccite might help. That won't disable citations in LoF and friends, but it will avoid the numbering getting confused by the LoF." -> This option really worked, but \usepackage{notoccite} chages the font of table of content where the line spacing is increased. Could you please help to resolve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: It's probably a clash with some code or a package used in your custom document class `utmthesis`. Hard to say without knowing what the class does.